# Remove a certain json field using logstash

Tags: json, logstash-configuration

I need to remove entries having key as 404. My current filter doesn't seem to work.

I need to only remove the field and not the entire row.

```
  if [net][status] == "404" {
mutate {
  remove_field => [ "[url][queryString]" ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove entries I recommend using drop{ }.  This stops the record from progressing through the logstash pipeline.  All you are doing is removing a specific "field" from your record.

```
if [net][status] == "404" {
    drop{ }
}
```

Comment: Does drop{} remove one entire entry?? How do we remove a specific field like [url][querystring]?? The format is json

Comment: This doesn't work because I have to work on the key and not the value.